# Asp.Net MVC 4 Windows authentication IIS on WIndows 8 returns domainname\machinename not username

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, iis

I have a MVC 4 application running on Windows 8/VS 2012 using Windows Authentication. It works just fine with the VS development server returning DOMAINNAME\USERNAME as the identity. However after deploying to local IIS it returns DOMAINNAME\MACHINENAME.

I have checked the usual stuff on the W8 IIS. The only thing I can see is that Windows Forms authentication is missing as an option on the virtual directory but I cannot see/find anyway to add it.

Under a bit of pressure timewise so help very welcome indeed!